# how to call postgres function with hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am getting sorted results using hibernate criteria which generates the below sql:

```
select * from mytable order by name asc;
```

This is how i do it with hiberante criteria:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("name"));
```

Now, i have created a function in postgres DB as: customSort(text)

and want to use with hibernate criteria such that following sql is generated:

```
select * from mytable order by customSort(name) asc;
```

How can i call this function in hibernate to make my custom sorting and generate equivalent sql?

Any code sample will help alot

Thanks,
Akhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent some time on this and found a solution by extendeding a class CustomOrder.java from Order.java and override the toString() method as below:

```
public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
            throws HibernateException
    {
        String[] columns = criteriaQuery.getColumnsUsingProjection(criteria, propertyName);
        Type type = criteriaQuery.getTypeUsingProjection(criteria, propertyName);
        StringBuffer fragment = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
        {
            SessionFactoryImplementor factory = criteriaQuery.getFactory();
            fragment.append("customOrder");
            fragment.append("(");
            boolean lower = ignoreCase && type.sqlTypes(factory)[i] == Types.VARCHAR;
            if (lower)
            {
                fragment.append(factory.getDialect().getLowercaseFunction())
                        .append('(');
            }
            fragment.append(columns[i]);
            if (lower)
                fragment.append(')');
            fragment.append(")");
            fragment.append(ascending ? " asc" : " desc");
            if (i < columns.length - 1)
                fragment.append(", ");
        }
        return fragment.toString();
    }
```

then we need to call :

```
criteria.addOrder(CustomOrder.asc("name"));
```

instead of calling criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("name"))

this worked and i was able to place DB method call in where clause as

```
select * from mytable order by customSort(name) asc;
```

I am just wondering is there a similar way such that i can place this function call in select part also using criteria??
for example:

```
select customSort(col1), col2, col3 from mytable order by customSort(name) asc;
```

pelase post your suggestions.

Comment: Seems like you are going to a lot of effort and creating unneeded hard to follow code to just run a stored procedure. I feel sorry for the guy who has to maintain your code in a couple years.

Answer (score 1):

Use Hibernate [Native SqlQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) to acheive this.

You cannot access a Database specific native functions in criterial queries.

```
sess.createSQLQuery("select * from mytable order by
                                        customSort(name) asc").list();
```

Comment: Thanks baadshah, but i just want to avoid the hardcoded sql. is there any different way?

Comment: AFAIK, No.Sorry,I do not know if is there any other way.

Comment: Pretty sure you can map the procedure and then invoke it from Criteria, but I'm blessedly free of having to work with JPA anymore.