# Hibernate nested query using criteria

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Is it posible to create a criteria for generating below sql:

```
select name from (select distinct name from person) as aliasname  order by lower(name);
```

here there are two sql -

1. `select distinct name from person`
2. `select name from <output of 1> as aliasname order by lower(name)`

i want to create the criteria and then do `criteria.list()`

Answer (score 1):

I think, this will suit your needs:

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("name").ignoreCase())
        .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("name")))
        .list();
```

or, this criteria uses a DetachedCriteria with a name projection as a subquery:

```
DetachedCriteria distinctNamesCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Person.class);
distinctNamesCriteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("name")));

criteria.add(SubQueries.propertyIn("name", distinctNamesCriteria))
        .addOrder(Order.asc("name").ignoreCase())
        .list();
```

Comment: Dear OGZD, In your sugession, two things are missing: 1. it does not apply lower(need to use .ignoreCase()), 2. it does not give nested select. Since this query "select distinct name from person order by lower(name);" is failing in postgres, I am looking for workaround query as described in the question as "select name from (select distinct name from person) as aliasname  order by lower(name)"

Comment: are you sure that the result set returned by the genereated query will be same as mentioned in question?? well I have already tried this before your updated code and got different result set. This criteria will not actually return the DISTINCT records. Will be great if you refer a similar [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313502/how-to-create-hibernate-criteria-with-distinct-in-this-case) to answer this question

Answer (score -1):

I don't have an answer for you, but why are you you doing a second select?

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM PERSON AS ALIASNAME ORDER BY LOWER(NAME)
```

would return the same data.

Comment: This actually gives an error in postgres as: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list. so I am going for two selects (nested)

Comment: You can't order by column not present in `select` part.